# Instantiating IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> with an array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, c#-4.0

I probably miss something with array construction syntax in c#. If I have the following function (thanks to type variance feature in c# 4):

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> test<T>()
{
        return new List<List<T>>();
}
```

How can I write similar one that instantiates array of array?

Comment: Does return new Array<Array<T>>(); not work?

Comment: The non-generic type 'System.Array' cannot be used with type arguments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> test<T>()
{
        return new [] { new T[] {} };
}
```

<sub>I noticed that there used to be a bug in the mono compiler (at least, the 2.6.7 gmcs would crash...) that required you to spell `new IEnumerable<T>[] { new T[] {}}`; This is no longer a problem with e.g. mono 2.11</sub>

#### Alternatively

you could use a yield block (which would be less efficient)

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> test<T>()
{
        yield return new T[] {};
}
```

#### `Enumerable.Empty<>`

Are you aware of `Enumerable.Empty<>`?

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> test<T>()
{
        return Enumerable.Empty<IEnumerable<T>>();
}
```

Comment: Added trivia about crashing mono compiler versions on this particular sample. Duh... :)

Comment: Wow! Enumerable.Empty<> looks the best! Never used it before.